# Jquery get text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I use the following, I get this.  Why does it not just return the exact value and not show the rest.  I just want it to show "CVC" and "ACLYAU", instead of "{ Value = ACLYAU }" and "{ Value = ACLYAU }".  When I try to pass this to my controller it breaks.

```
@Html.Hidden("princid", new { @Value = (@TempData["PrincId"]) })
@Html.Hidden("custid", new { @Value = (@TempData["CustId"]) })

  <script>
    var val = $("#princid").val();
    var val2 = $("#custid").val();

    alert(val);
    alert(val2);
  </script>
```

result

```
===>     "{ Value = CVC }"
===>     "{ Value = ACLYAU }"
```

desired output

```
   "CVC"
   "ACLYAU"
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
@Html.Hidden("princid", new { @Value = (@TempData["PrincId"]) })
@Html.Hidden("custid", new { @Value = (@TempData["CustId"]) })
```

by this:

```
@Html.Hidden("princid", (object)@TempData["PrincId"])
@Html.Hidden("custid", (object)@TempData["CustId"])
```